# Upsource with GitLab as Oauth

Tags: oauth, gitlab, upsource

I'm running GitLab on local address http://192.168.0.18/. Upsource is running on http://192.168.0.11/.

I've added Upsource application as admin on GitLab. I've set client id and secret token as GitLab said. Authorization is set to http://192.168.0.18/oauth/authorize, token to http://192.168.0.18/oauth/token and user data to http://192.168.0.18/api/v4/user (according to [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/oauth2.html)). In field mappings, I've set User ID to "id" and both e-mails to "email".

Then, on logging page of Upsource, I've oath authentication icon. After clicking on it, GitLab requires logging and user has to authorize application for its account:

> Authorization required
>
> Authorize Upsource to use your account?
>
> You are an admin, which means granting access to Upsource will allow them to interact with GitLab as an admin as well. Proceed with caution.
>
> This application will be able to:
>
> Access your API
>
> Read user information

Hovewer, after clicking `authorize` button, Upsource displays info: `Authentication failed. Check your credentials and try again.`. What have I set wrong? Field mappings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I've found the answer. As happens often, I was fighting with this a good amount of hours and just after I asked this question, I've got idea to run this on my own. Rubber duck method, I guess...

As I suspected, the problem was in field mappings.

I looked in `Network` tab in Chrome and there was this response:

> http://192.168.0.11/hub/auth/login?response_type=token&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&message=hub-auth-failed&developer_message=getValueByPath%28json%2C+aut%E2%80%A6userIdPath%29%21%21.textValue%28%29+must+not+be+null

I've manually went through all Gitlab workflow and then I could log in - and after running http://192.168.0.18/api/v4/user endpoint, I've got user data:

> {"name":"username","username":"username","id":3,"state":"active","avatar_url":"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/94232f2d1f8bb2fe940de439a4df1014?s=80&d=identicon","web_url":"http://debian/username","created_at":"2017-03-25T22:28:21.375Z","is_admin":true,"bio":null,"location":null,"skype":"","linkedin":"","twitter":"","website_url":"","organization":null,"last_sign_in_at":"2017-03-25T22:28:21.487Z","confirmed_at":"2017-03-25T22:28:21.376Z","email":"username@username.username","color_scheme_id":1,"projects_limit":100000,"current_sign_in_at":"2017-03-25T22:36:31.853Z","identities":[],"can_create_group":true,"can_create_project":true,"two_factor_enabled":false,"external":false}

The problem was in setting ID field name. As we can see in above JSON data, `id` field should be mapped to `name`/`username`, not `id` itself. 
After this change I could sucessfully login into Upsource.